# .htaccess Redirect /sub_dir/img to use /img instead

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file inside a directory called `www/sub_dir`. The index file in that `sub_dir` directory calls `img/logo.png`.

Instead of using a full path for all of my images can I just put an `.htaccess` file which will look in the `www/img` directory instead of the `www/sub_dir/img` for the files?

Answer (score 0):

if www is your web root, you can just put a leading `/` on the uri for the image. For example if your image is at `http://www.yoursite.com/img/logo.png`, any sub-directory on the site you can put `/img/logo.png` to access it. the leading `/` just means "top level". so `/img/logo.png` means "top level, then the `img` folder, then the file `logo.png`"

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider using `<base href="...">`, if applicable. This way, regardless of which sub-directory you're in, you can still use `img/`, `css/`, etc.
2. If this is a single specific folder, consider using `symlinks`. Just `ln -s ../img .` and add `Options +FollowSymLinks` to apache configuration or .htaccess.
3. You could easily use `/img/logo.png` or `../img/logo.png` in your files in subfolder...
4. If neither of the suggestions above are an option, add the following rewrite rules into your web root .htaccess:

   `RewriteEngine on`

   `RewriteBase /`

   `RewriteRule ^sub_folder/(img/.*) $1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess file in your /www/sub_dir/img/ directory

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ /www/img/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /(img/.+)$ $1 [NC,L]
```